# Android - cannot correctly parse the date of tomorrow

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the date of tomorrow and insert it into a Date type variable, but for some reason I'm getting an empty string.

Here his the code:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
String time_Date_str = cal.getTime().toString();
try
{
    Date myDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm").parse(time_Date_str);
    Toast.makeText(this, "time_Date_str", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    t.setDueDate(myDate);
    t.setHasDate(true);
} catch(Exception e){myDate=null;}
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using your `sdf` variable to format the date...  try this:

```
String time_Date_str = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!